A 4-dimensional 3-handle attachment to $S^2 \times D^2$ to get $D^4$.
Given $Y= S^1\times D^2$ and attaching sphere of 3-handle as $S= S^2 \times \{pt\}$, then how to visualise that after attaching 3-handle we get $D^4$ as the resultant manifold?
This is part of the Remark 4.4.1 from the book "Kirby Calculus and 4-manifolds'' by Gompf and Stipsicz.
My idea of proving above is as follows.
We know $\partial Y= S^2 \times S^1$. We are attaching $S^2 \times \{pt\}$ with the attaching region $S^2\times D^1$ (by the definition of a handle attachment). While attaching the attaching region of 3-handle, we identify it with $S^2 \times D^1 \subset \partial Y$. Thus, the remaining unglued boundary of $\partial Y$ is $S^2\times D^1$ (after smoothing of handle attachment). And the remaining boundary of the resultant manifold $X$ comes from boundary of the handle, which is $D^3 \times S^0$.
Therefore, $\partial X= S^2\times D^1 \cup D^3 \times S^0= S^3$.
Now, how can be deduced that the resultant 4-manifold $X$ is $D^4$?
Any help/hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Manifold X is contractible. Because $S^2\times D^2$ is contractible to $S^2$ and $S^2$ is getting killed in 3-handle attachment. Thus, X is contractible. Moreover, any contractible 4-manifold with boundary $S^3$ is $D^4$. Suppose M is a contractible 4-manifold with $S^3$ as boundary. Consider its handle body decomposition. If it has any handle of middle dimension in non cancelling position, then they corresponds non trivial homology group of their index, contradicting to contractibility. Since 4-manifold has non empty boundary its uncapped. Thus, M is just a 0-handle, ie, $D^4$.

You can first imagine the picture in one dimension lower. Think of $S^2\times I$ as a tubular neighbood of the standard $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Then attaching a $3$-handle along the inner $S^2$ fills in the hole and gives you $D^3$. Now multiplying everything by $I$ yields the picture you want.
